# accessing only left eigenvectors in armadillo c

Tags: linear-algebra, armadillo

I am using eig-gen function from the armadillo library and getting the left and right eigenvectors/eigenvalues together, meaning the elements are appearing as (1,2), (3,4)  .
Is there a way to access only the left eigenvectors/eigenvalues at one time since I want to perform manipulation on them ?
If not, how to access corresponding left and right elements from these dual elements ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[answer withdrawn, as upstream documentation no longer describes the function mentioned in the answer]